# Nesting in helm chart expression

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm trying to get a random value but wants to divide it with 2. Is it possible to nest expression in helm chart or use one [helm template function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/) inside another? Something like below

```
{{ div {{randNumeric 2 }} 2 }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you're inside the `{{ ... }}`, you're evaluating a template expression.  The template language includes parenthesized subexpressions

```
{{ div (randNumeric 2) 2 }}
```

You can't nest the `{{ ... }}` (and don't need to).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `include` function for using a template inside another template.

As helm official [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/):

> Go provides a way of including one template in another using a built-in template directive. However, the built-in function cannot be used in Go template pipelines.
>
> To make it possible to include a template, and then perform an operation on that template's output, Helm has a special include function:

`{{ include "toYaml" $value | indent 2 }}`
The above includes a template called `toYaml`, passes it `$value`, and then passes the output of that template to the `indent` function.